# Summing GroupFooter2 data from GroupFooter1 data

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Is there a way to summarize data in a group footer band from another in FastReports 5 Embarcadero Edition?

I have a FastReport which displays weekly time sheets for a monthly period. Daily time in and out, and time elapsed are displayed in MasterBand1.  Time elapsed, clockable hours and calculation of straight time are in the weekly summary in GroupFooter1.  I need to also summarize this information in GroupFooter2 for the month.

Clockable hours are those in which the employee actually works.  Sick, personal and vacation time are excluded. Total hours include clockable and non-clockable.

Overtime is calculated as the number of clockable hours in excess of 40 hours in a week.  I am able to use variables to calculate each of these in the (weekly) GroupFooter1 bank. In order for the monthly totals for overtime and straight time to be accurate, I must accumulate the straight and over time from the weekly band rather than the master data band.  Since FastReports Embarcadero Edition does not include scripting, I am at a loss as to how to do this using variables. The only alternative I can think of is to create calculated fields in a "month" dataset for each employee and link that dataset to GroupFooter2. There creates the possiblity, however, of errors by presenting data from two different sources. Is there a way to do this within FastReports?

Here is the .pas for the form.

```
unit YTDPayRpt;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
  FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def,
  FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.FB,
  FireDAC.Phys.FBDef, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS,
  FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, Vcl.StdCtrls, frxClass, frxDBSet, Data.DB,
  FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.Comp.UI, frxChBox;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Connection: TFDConnection;
    WaitCursor: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    WorkshiftDataset: TFDTable;
    Report: TfrxReport;
    frxDBDataset1: TfrxDBDataset;
    Button1: TButton;
    frxCheckBoxObject1: TfrxCheckBoxObject;
    WorkshiftDatasetID: TLargeintField;
    WorkshiftDatasetEMPLOYEEID: TLargeintField;
    WorkshiftDatasetJOBCODE: TSmallintField;
    WorkshiftDatasetCLOCKABLE: TBooleanField;
    WorkshiftDatasetDAYOFWEEK: TStringField;
    WorkshiftDatasetDATEIN: TDateField;
    WorkshiftDatasetTIMEIN: TTimeField;
    WorkshiftDatasetDATEOUT: TDateField;
    WorkshiftDatasetTIMEOUT: TTimeField;
    WorkshiftDatasetNOTE: TMemoField;
    WorkshiftDatasetTIMEELAPSED: TFMTBCDField;
    WorkshiftDatasetWEEKOF: TDateField;
    WorkshiftDatasetROWNBR: TSmallintField;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Report.ShowReport();
end;

end.
```

Here is text file for the form with componenets needed for the report.

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 211
  ClientWidth = 418
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 184
    Top = 112
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Connection: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      'ConnectionDef=Timedata - Local')
    Connected = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    Left = 96
    Top = 24
  end
  object WaitCursor: TFDGUIxWaitCursor
    Provider = 'Forms'
    Left = 208
    Top = 24
  end
  object WorkshiftDataset: TFDTable
    Active = True
    IndexFieldNames = 'ID;DATEIN;ROWNBR'
    Connection = Connection
    UpdateOptions.UpdateTableName = 'V_WORKSHIFT'
    TableName = 'V_WORKSHIFT'
    Left = 288
    Top = 32
    object WorkshiftDatasetID: TLargeintField
      FieldName = 'ID'
      Origin = 'ID'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetEMPLOYEEID: TLargeintField
      FieldName = 'EMPLOYEEID'
      Origin = 'EMPLOYEEID'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetJOBCODE: TSmallintField
      FieldName = 'JOBCODE'
      Origin = 'JOBCODE'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetCLOCKABLE: TBooleanField
      FieldName = 'CLOCKABLE'
      Origin = 'CLOCKABLE'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetDAYOFWEEK: TStringField
      FieldName = 'DAYOFWEEK'
      Origin = 'DAYOFWEEK'
      Size = 10
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetDATEIN: TDateField
      FieldName = 'DATEIN'
      Origin = 'DATEIN'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetTIMEIN: TTimeField
      FieldName = 'TIMEIN'
      Origin = 'TIMEIN'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetDATEOUT: TDateField
      FieldName = 'DATEOUT'
      Origin = 'DATEOUT'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetTIMEOUT: TTimeField
      FieldName = 'TIMEOUT'
      Origin = 'TIMEOUT'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetNOTE: TMemoField
      FieldName = 'NOTE'
      Origin = 'NOTE'
      BlobType = ftMemo
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetTIMEELAPSED: TFMTBCDField
      FieldName = 'TIMEELAPSED'
      Origin = 'TIMEELAPSED'
      Precision = 18
      Size = 9
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetWEEKOF: TDateField
      FieldName = 'WEEKOF'
      Origin = 'WEEKOF'
    end
    object WorkshiftDatasetROWNBR: TSmallintField
      FieldName = 'ROWNBR'
      Origin = 'ROWNBR'
    end
  end
  object Report: TfrxReport
    Version = '5.3.14'
    DotMatrixReport = False
    IniFile = '\Software\Fast Reports'
    PreviewOptions.Buttons = [pbPrint, pbLoad, pbSave, pbExport, pbZoom, pbFind, pbOutline, pbPageSetup, pbTools, pbEdit, pbNavigator, pbExportQuick]
    PreviewOptions.Zoom = 1.000000000000000000
    PrintOptions.Printer = 'Default'
    PrintOptions.PrintOnSheet = 0
    ReportOptions.CreateDate = 42689.921906956000000000
    ReportOptions.LastChange = 42689.930818541700000000
    ScriptLanguage = 'PascalScript'
    ScriptText.Strings = (
      ''
      'begin'
      ''
      'end.')
    Left = 56
    Top = 103
    Datasets = <
      item
        DataSet = frxDBDataset1
        DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
      end>
    Variables = <
      item
        Name = ' Workshift'
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'ClockableTime'
        Value = 
          'iif(<frxDBDataset1."CLOCKABLE"> = true, <frxDBDataset1."TIMEELAP' +
          'SED"> * 24, 0)'
      end
      item
        Name = 'WeeklyTimeElapsed'
        Value = 'SUM(<frxDBDataset1."TIMEELAPSED"> * 24,MasterData1)'
      end
      item
        Name = 'WeeklyClockableTime'
        Value = 'sum(<ClockableTime>)'
      end
      item
        Name = 'WeeklyStraightTime'
        Value = '<WeeklyTimeElapsed> - <WeeklyOvertime>'
      end
      item
        Name = 'WeeklyOvertime'
        Value = 'iif(<WeeklyClockableTime> > 40, <WeeklyTimeElapsed> - 40, 0)'
      end
      item
        Name = 'EmployeeTimeElapsed'
        Value = 'sum(<frxDBDataset1."TIMEELAPSED">, MasterData1)'
      end>
    Style = <>
    object Data: TfrxDataPage
      Height = 1000.000000000000000000
      Width = 1000.000000000000000000
    end
    object Page1: TfrxReportPage
      PaperWidth = 215.900000000000000000
      PaperHeight = 279.400000000000000000
      PaperSize = 1
      LeftMargin = 10.000000000000000000
      RightMargin = 10.000000000000000000
      TopMargin = 10.000000000000000000
      BottomMargin = 10.000000000000000000
      object MasterData1: TfrxMasterData
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 28.800000000000000000
        Top = 201.600000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
        DataSet = frxDBDataset1
        DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
        RowCount = 0
        object frxDBDataset1JOBCODE: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 172.800000000000000000
          Width = 124.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataField = 'JOBCODE'
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[frxDBDataset1."JOBCODE"]')
        end
        object frxDBDataset1DATEIN: TfrxMemoView
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataField = 'DATEIN'
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[frxDBDataset1."DATEIN"]')
        end
        object frxDBDataset1DAYOFWEEK: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 86.400000000000000000
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataField = 'DAYOFWEEK'
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[frxDBDataset1."DAYOFWEEK"]')
        end
        object frxDBDataset1TIMEIN: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 307.200000000000000000
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataField = 'TIMEIN'
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[frxDBDataset1."TIMEIN"]')
        end
        object frxDBDataset1TIMEOUT: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 393.600000000000000000
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataField = 'TIMEOUT'
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[frxDBDataset1."TIMEOUT"]')
        end
        object frxDBDataset1TIMEELAPSED: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 480.000000000000000000
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          DisplayFormat.FormatStr = '%2.2n'
          DisplayFormat.Kind = fkNumeric
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clBlack
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Arial'
          Font.Style = []
          HAlign = haRight
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[<frxDBDataset1."TIMEELAPSED"> * 24]')
          ParentFont = False
        end
        object Memo3: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 566.400000000000000000
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          DisplayFormat.FormatStr = '%2.2n'
          DisplayFormat.Kind = fkNumeric
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clBlack
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Arial'
          Font.Style = []
          HAlign = haRight
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[ClockableTime]')
          ParentFont = False
        end
        object CheckBox1: TfrxCheckBoxView
          Left = 662.400000000000000000
          Width = 18.897650000000000000
          Height = 18.897650000000000000
          CheckColor = clBlack
          CheckStyle = csCheck
          DataField = 'CLOCKABLE'
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
        end
      end
      object PageFooter1: TfrxPageFooter
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 28.800000000000000000
        Top = 441.600000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
        object Memo1: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 665.197280000000000000
          Width = 75.590600000000000000
          Height = 18.897650000000000000
          HAlign = haRight
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[Page#]')
        end
      end
      object PageHeader1: TfrxPageHeader
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 28.800000000000000000
        Top = 19.200000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
      end
      object ReportSummary1: TfrxReportSummary
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 28.800000000000000000
        Top = 393.600000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
      end
      object GroupHeader1: TfrxGroupHeader
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 28.800000000000000000
        Top = 105.600000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
        Condition = 'frxDBDataset1."EMPLOYEEID"'
        StartNewPage = True
        object frxDBDataset1EMPLOYEEID: TfrxMemoView
          Width = 115.200000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataField = 'EMPLOYEEID'
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[frxDBDataset1."EMPLOYEEID"]')
        end
      end
      object GroupFooter1: TfrxGroupFooter
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 28.800000000000000000
        Top = 307.200000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
        object Memo7: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 460.800000000000000000
          Top = 9.600000000000023000
          Width = 96.000000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DisplayFormat.FormatStr = '%2.2n'
          DisplayFormat.Kind = fkNumeric
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clBlack
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Arial'
          Font.Style = []
          HAlign = haRight
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[SUM(<frxDBDataset1."TIMEELAPSED"> * 24,MasterData1)]')
          ParentFont = False
        end
      end
      object GroupHeader2: TfrxGroupHeader
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 28.800000000000000000
        Top = 153.600000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
        Condition = 'frxDBDataset1."WEEKOF"'
        object frxDBDataset1WEEKOF: TfrxMemoView
          Width = 105.600000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DataSet = frxDBDataset1
          DataSetName = 'frxDBDataset1'
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            'w/o [frxDBDataset1."WEEKOF"]')
        end
      end
      object GroupFooter2: TfrxGroupFooter
        FillType = ftBrush
        Height = 38.400000000000000000
        Top = 249.600000000000000000
        Width = 740.409927000000000000
        object Memo2: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 480.000000000000000000
          Top = 9.599999999999995000
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DisplayFormat.FormatStr = '%2.2n'
          DisplayFormat.Kind = fkNumeric
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clBlack
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Arial'
          Font.Style = []
          HAlign = haRight
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[WeeklyTimeElapsed]')
          ParentFont = False
        end
        object Memo4: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 566.400000000000000000
          Top = 9.599999999999995000
          Width = 76.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DisplayFormat.FormatStr = '%2.2n'
          DisplayFormat.Kind = fkNumeric
          Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
          Font.Color = clBlack
          Font.Height = -13
          Font.Name = 'Arial'
          Font.Style = []
          HAlign = haRight
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            '[WeeklyClockableTime]')
          ParentFont = False
        end
        object Memo5: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 9.600000000000000000
          Top = 9.599999999999995000
          Width = 201.600000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DisplayFormat.FormatStr = '%2.2n'
          DisplayFormat.Kind = fkNumeric
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            'Straight Time:  [WeeklyStraightTime]')
        end
        object Memo6: TfrxMemoView
          Left = 220.800000000000000000
          Top = 9.599999999999995000
          Width = 172.800000000000000000
          Height = 19.200000000000000000
          DisplayFormat.FormatStr = '%2.2n'
          DisplayFormat.Kind = fkNumeric
          Memo.UTF8W = (
            'Overtime hours:  [WeeklyOvertime]')
        end
      end
    end
  end
  object frxDBDataset1: TfrxDBDataset
    UserName = 'frxDBDataset1'
    CloseDataSource = False
    DataSet = WorkshiftDataset
    BCDToCurrency = False
    Left = 360
    Top = 32
  end
  object frxCheckBoxObject1: TfrxCheckBoxObject
    Left = 112
    Top = 112
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a screen capture of your Report design page so we can see the disposition of those groups?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SUM(iif(<frxDBDataset1."CLOCKABLE"> = true, <frxDBDataset1."TIMEELAP' +
          'SED"> * 24, 0), MasterData1)
```

expression in the TfrxMemoView on the GroupFooter2